# Java / Postgres SQL import speed discrepencies

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, ubuntu

I have a process which fetches data from a service and then inserts it into a table.

When I run it locally,

2017-07-05 10:59:51 - Fetched 5393 invalids - 7011ms

2017-07-05 10:59:54 - Fetched 440 blocked - 2906ms

2017-07-05 11:00:03 - Fetched 20778 bounces - 8206ms

2017-07-05 11:00:09 - Inserted invalids to database - **5705ms**

2017-07-05 11:00:09 - Inserted blocked to database - **512ms**

2017-07-05 11:00:29 - Inserted bounced to database - **19810ms**

When I run it on production

2017-07-05 11:10:31 - Fetched 5392 invalids - 5126ms

2017-07-05 11:10:34 - Fetched 440 blocked - 2421ms

2017-07-05 11:10:50 - Fetched 20778 bounces - 16105ms

2017-07-05 11:11:10 - Inserted invalids to database - **19795ms**

2017-07-05 11:11:12 - Inserted blocked to database - **1551ms**

2017-07-05 11:12:22 - Inserted bounced to database - **70770ms**

It is almost 4x slower..

Production is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v2 @ 2.60GHz

Local is Core i7-2630QM @ 2.00GHZ

So I don't really understand why there is such a difference.

I am not sure if there is some postgres tuning I can do?

Here is my insert method:
http://puu.sh/wC4vT/44d3516df1.png
Here I am getting a connection from the pool for every insert,

I previously was re-using the same connection for the inserts, which worked just as efficiently on local
http://puu.sh/wC4xD/7693ad63d3.png

Any advice would be hugely appreciated

Comment: It looks like a database configuration issue. Can you monitor database activity during the import ?

Comment: Yes. Profile the systems and try to spot the difference. As it is, the question is too vague to answer.

Comment: I am not a postgres expert.. i am not really sure what commands to run and what I should be looking for.. Can you advise please?

Comment: Assuming Linux: try `perf` (or `oprofile` on older systems) to see where the time is spent. Use [pgBadger](http://dalibo.github.io/pgbadger/) to analyze the database logs and spot time consuming queries.

Comment: Cool thanks, will look into those. Thanks. There is only one insert statement happening so that is the slow thing, there aren't any queries

Answer (score 0):

So the speed issue had nothing to do with the code or postgres configs - it was that my local machine is running on an SSD and the other servers are not..
So while they're beefier machices, doing 28000 single writes means 28000 flushes to disk.
I resolved the issue by doing batch inserts. The difference is incredible.

http://puu.sh/wHH0i/f3250caa03.png

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Don't forget to add another `executeBatch()`  **after** the `for` loop. Otherwise your loop only works correctly if the number of rows is an exact multiple of the batch size

Comment: I cater for the the last iteration of the loop with if (i % 1000 == 0 || i == data.length()-1) {...}